# ¿Como mostrar un boton con Javascript después de Iniciar sesión en un login (wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Saludos

Quisiera mostrar un botón oculto después de iniciar sesion en un custom login que hice en wordpress, 
funciona con el *action="/wp-login.php"* y despues redirecciona

```
function Login_Mapa($AdministradorMapa) {
   
    document.getElementById("modificarMapa").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("crearMapa").style.display = "block";
}
add_action('wp_login', 'Login_Mapa',10,1);
```

Gracias de antemano (:

Answer (score 0):

Si alguien esta interesado lo resolví, utilizando este código, que se carga después de logear con un usuario especifico y muestra los div ocultos que puse en elementor:

```
function action_wp_footer(  ) { 
global $current_user;
get_current_user_id();
if ($current_user->ID == '4') { 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'document.getElementById("crearMapa").style.display = "block";';
    echo 'document.getElementById("modificarMapa").style.display = "block";';
    echo '</script>';
}
else { 
 
}
}; 
         

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer', 10, 0 );
```